# Using Apache LogFactory on Android

Tags: java, android, apache, logging

I am migrating some Java code to Android. The codebase contain quite a bit LogFactory.getLog(xxx). The LogFactory comes from org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

How can I use it in Android, if not, what is the best replacement for it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/android/) which will wrap the Android logging functions. Just be aware that the jar files on the site are now behind the source held in git, and the 1.6.1-RC1 jar has been a 'Release Candidate' since 2010.